# Getting elements from an HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I toyed around with HList and the following works as expected:

```
val hl = 1 :: "foo" :: HNil
val i: Int = hl(_0)
val s: String = hl(_1)
```

However, I can't get the following piece of code working (let's assume for a moment random access on lists is a smart idea ;-)):

```
class Container(hl: HList) {
    def get(n: Nat) = hl(n)
}

val container = new Container(1 :: "foo" :: HNil)
val i: Int = container.get(_0)
val s: String = container.get(_1)
```

I'd like to have `get` return an `Int` and `String` according to it's parameter.  I assume, if possible at all, I have to use `Aux` or `at` but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something along these lines,

```
scala> import shapeless._, nat._, ops.hlist._
import shapeless._
import nat._
import ops.hlist._

scala> class Container[L <: HList](hl: L) {
     |   def get(n: Nat)(implicit at: At[L, n.N]): at.Out = hl[n.N]
     | }
defined class Container

scala> val container = new Container(1 :: "foo" :: HNil)
container: Container[shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]] = ...

scala> container.get(_0)
res1: Int = 1

scala> container.get(_1)
res2: String = foo
```

The first crucial difference here is that rather than typing `hl` as plain `HList`, which loses all specific information about the types of the elements, we parametrize over the precise type of the argument and preserve its structure as `L`. The second difference is that we use `L` to index the implicit `At` type class instance which is used to perform the indexing in `get`.

Also note that because there is an implicit conversion from `Int` literals to `Nat`'s you can write,

```
scala> container.get(0)
res3: Int = 1

scala> container.get(1)
res4: String = foo
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your library!